# win32ole error when using Worksheets function in ruby script

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'win32ole'
    $excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
    $excel.visible = true

    puts 'Filepath?'
    $filepath = $stdin.gets.chomp
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filepath);

    puts 'Sheet?' 
    $worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets
    $count = $worksheet.Count
    for i in 1..$count do 
        $array = $worksheet(i).Name
        puts i.to_s + "." + " " + $array
    end
    $sheetnumber = $stdin.gets.chomp

    excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0);
    excel.Quit();
```

I'm fairly new to Ruby so the answer could be extremely obvious and sorry if it is. However, the problem I'm having is that whenever I try to run this code I get the following error message:

```
Git.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end
        $array = $worksheet(i).Name
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. Even if I try

```
puts $worksheet(1).Name
```

It doesn't work. Had built this same script a week ago and it worked fine. I did build it on a older version of Ruby however so that might be the case. So ideally if anybody could answer why this is happening that would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$worksheet` is likely an array. In Ruby, you should use square brackets to reference an element from an array instead of parenthesis :

```
$worksheet(i) => $worksheet[i]
```

Comment: Wow can't believe I missed that. Thank you

Comment: Friend, I think you are coming from a PHP background. It would be good if you don't use global variables (`$<var>`) unnecessarily, it has already brought trouble in your code -- you forgot to use it on `excel` in last two lines. Try to use interpolation over `+`ing strings, it will keep things simple and you won't have to convert anything to string manually. Also don't use a semi-colon when you have only one statement on a line. And parenthesis when calling a function is optional, so you can simply use `excel.Quit` (looks better right ^^). Don't capitalize method names, too. Welcome to Ruby!